Google Identity getAuthToken interactive option doesn't work
In my chrome extension, I am trying to provide my users with a login screen to choose which account they log into my extension with. However, even though I set the "interactive" flag to "true" in the Chrome getAuth API, the menu doesn't show up.
import type { PlasmoMessaging } from "@plasmohq/messaging"
import { Storage } from "@plasmohq/storage"

const handler: PlasmoMessaging.MessageHandler = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const forceInteractivity = req.body.forceInteractivity || false
    const storage = new Storage()

    // Directly use await since getAuthToken returns a Promise in Chrome 105+
    const token = await chrome.identity.getAuthToken({
      interactive: forceInteractivity
    })
    console.log("Interactive:", forceInteractivity, "Token:", token)

    if (token) {
      await storage.set("authToken", token)
    }
    res.send({ token })
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("There was an error in googleAuth.ts")
    console.error(err)
    res.send({ err })
  }
}

export default handler

Console.log shows this: "Interactive: true Token: {grantedScopes: Array(5), token: 'myToken'}". What am I missing?
